# Retrieve timezone aware DateTimeField in Django

Tags: django, pytz

In my models, I have a `DateTimeField` say

```
class ReturnEvent(models.Model):
  book_title = models.CharField()
  return_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

When I retrieve the `return_time` to be printed, for example:

```
return_event = ReturnEvent.objects.get(id=1)
print(return_event.return_time.strftime("%H:%M"))
```

I am seeing the datetime **unaware** time like:

`2016-06-18 08:18:00+00:00`

However, I like to see the local time using strftime.

`2016-06-18 10:18:00+02:00`

Is there a quick solution for this?

Comment: Do you have `USE_TZ = True` set in `settings.py`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have `USE_TZ = True` in your settings, Django stores all the datetime objects in the database as `UTC` and convert them to your `TIME_ZONE=XYZ` from `settings.py` on the fly when rendering in the templates.

That is why, when retrieved from the database, `datetime` object is timezone aware but it has `UTC` as its timezone (hence `+00:00` in `2016-06-18 08:18:00+00:00`). As, you are converting the time to `str` yourself (and not rendering in the template) so Django does not convert it to your `TIME_ZONE` setting. You need to convert it yourself to your desired TimeZone.

If you want to convert it to the TimeZone from your `TIME_ZONE` setting, you can do

```
from django.utils import timezone
to_tz = timezone.get_default_timezone()
print return_event.return_time.astimezone(to_tz).strftime("%H:%M")
```