# Django timezone gives wrong result even though USE_TZ = True

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a model like this:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()   
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

The date_added displayed in the template:

```
{% localtime on %}
  {{ entry.date_added|date:'d M, Y H:i'}}  
{% endlocaltime %}
```

As suggested in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones.

In my setting.py, my `USE_TZ = True`

However, the output gives me`datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 22, 9, 20, 16, 439533, tzinfo=<UTC>)`
or 22 Aug, 2020 9:20 in my webpage

Why does the output be in UTC? In my understanding, aware datetime means it follows the user's timezone. My timezone is UTC+7, so it must be 22 Aug 2020 16:20.

I've read [Retrieve timezone aware DateTimeField in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527186/retrieve-timezone-aware-datetimefield-in-django) that suggests changing `TIME_ZONE =`  but wouldn't that makes it unaware?

What can I do to fix it? I expect the datetime follows the user's timezone

Thank you

Comment: Which timezone is you required ??

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py file please set the following.

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
USE_TZ = False
```

Comment: Reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones

Comment: But wouldn't that make the timezone naive?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to keep `USE_TZ = True`.

The `TIME_ZONE` setting is simply the default for your application.

To allow users to change their timezone you need to provide them with the ability to do so in your app. Once they have changed their timezone you use `timezone.activate()` to make their choice active.

See [this small example from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone) for more information.