# How to change datetype timestamp without timezone to timestamp with timezone in the Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

**models.py**

```
class sample(models.Model)
   a = models.DateTimeField(blank=true, default=true)
```

**POSTGRES sample Table**

```
a column datetype is a timestamp without timezone
```

I need to change 'a' column datetype timestamp without timezone to timestamp with timezone using Django model. how to achieve this scenario.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve timezone aware DateTimeField in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527186/retrieve-timezone-aware-datetimefield-in-django)

Comment: No, I need to change PostgreSQL datetype using Django migration